# OSX MySql terminal parameters

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

So I am going crazy with this. I have MAMP installed and it's MySQL is working fine. I now installed MySQL 5.7.19 from the official dmg from their site and installed.

From the pref panel I am not getting status updates and as such I cannot stop it even though it is running. Trivial though as I can launctl unload it.

However, the big issue I am facing is that although the server starts correctly (from pref panel) and I can see the process running and the respective /tmp/mysql.sock file when I try to run mysql in terminal (or any other mysql command) I get an error stating it cant find the sock file and it pipes out the Applications/MAMP path.

I looked everywhere for a my.cnf that might be setting this and there are none (apart from the one used by MAMP). No environment variables set to override it, nothing. In fact, there are no other my.cnf files but for some reason it still thinks it should be using /Applications/MAMP path.

`my_print_defaults client` confirms this as it pipes out

```
--socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

but I have absolutely no idea where and how this is being set and I need to be able to run on this instance terminal commands. Driving me crazy for hours now.

No files at

```
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

No environment variable MYSQL_UNIX_PORT as described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-mysql-sock.html

So how the heck is it getting this value?

Also checked at `DATA_DIR` and `BASE_DIR`, no my.cnf there either.

Obviously Ive done `which mysql` to confirm I am calling the correct binary.

Any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE** Running `my_print_defaults client --verbose --no-defaults` pipes the same exact output, so I am guessing it is somehow set elsewhere. Where can this variable be set otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer after all and sharing it for anyone having the same issue.

In essence, the --socket parameter is added via the ~/.mylogin.cnf file!

I am not sure if I ever added it there but I am pretty sure it wasn't me, so I am guessing MAMP did it.

This is an encrypted file so you can't edit it directly by you can change it via `mysql_config_editor`:

`mysql_config_editor remove --socket`

And problem solved!